# GAE - Flask can't import Jinja2 from subdirectory?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, flask, jinja2

I'm working on a Google App Engine project using Flask. Flask is then using Jinja2. When I put Flask and all its required modules into the root folder of my project, the server started up just fine. However, I wanted to clean up the directory a bit so I moved Flask and other modules (including Jinja2) to a subdirectory called 'lib'. So my project looks like:

```
app.yaml
main.py
myapp
    __init__.py
    view.py
    blahblah.py
lib
    flask
    jinja2
    OtherModules
```

Then in the main.py file of the app I add the directory using `sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')`. Flask seems to import fine using this method, but Flask does not seem to be able to find Jinja2 with them both in the lib folder. When attempting to access a view on my running dev_appserver test I get:

```
File "lib/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

How can I allow Flask to find Jinja2 (and allow other modules to find their requirements) while keeping them in the lib directory and not having to edit the modules to adjust paths?

Below is my main.py file in case something in there would be useful to know:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')

from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from myapp import app

run_wsgi_app(app)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to include Jinja in you app engine application in your app.yaml file add these lines

```
libraries:
  - name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) for including more of the available libraries.

In order to use it for your local server you should install these also to your system. In a unix like system it would be

```
sudo easy_install jinja2
```

Additional information: there is an open source [framework](http://gae-init.appspot.com) called gae-init, which combines your tech stack and provides a series of automations and good practices for app engine web services. Maybe worth having a look at it.